# Udp server and Qt, reliable way to determine if the socket is available

Tags: multithreading, qt, sockets, udp

With the Qt i'm trying to connect to a local udp socket.
What i am facing is a small issue but i would like it to address it properly for future projects as well.
The core software is divided in a main thread which Init the connection and a secondary thread that emits a signal when a third-party process (another application) is started to let the main thread try to connect to that process hosted server.

```
void MainWindow::initSocket(){

    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));

    handshaker s1;
    s1.a= 1;
    s1.b= 1;

    udpSocket->writeDatagram((const char*)&s1, sizeof(s1), QHostAddress::LocalHost, PORT);

    QThread::sleep(1);

    s1.c= 1;

    udpSocket->writeDatagram((const char*)&s1, sizeof(s1), QHostAddress::LocalHost, PORT);
}
```

What basically happens is that sometimes the signal is emitted too soon and the handshake is performed too soon (the packet get lost because there is no server on the other side), hence the connection is not properly established.
I know that UDP is connectionless but is there a reliable way to understand if the receiver is on (like a ping for example)?

if i type netstat -an | find "UDP" in the cmd i can defintely see when the server is available.

Comment: The code you've shown creates a new `QUdpSocket` and then immediately calls `writeDatagram` on it.  When you say "sometimes the signal is emitted too soon", which signal and from where?

Comment: The init function is called after the second thread emits the signal "thirdAppStarted" (let's say) hence the second recognizes that the third app is launched.